# Different behavior for calling function on non-object in javascript

Tags: javascript, this

Both firefox's js engine/gjs (spidermonkey) and webkit's jscore seems to have different behavior when calling builtin and normal js functions on non-object.

```
gjs> toString.call(null)
"[object Null]"
gjs> function cccc() {return toString.call(this);}
gjs> cccc.call(null)
"[object GjsGlobal]"
```

So if a normal js function is called with non-object, its `this` is automatically get replaced by the current `this`, whereas this won't happen for a builtin function.

Is this the standard behavior (according to some specification?) or is it just a implementation dependent behavior?
Is the first line always safe to check the type of any value?

THX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behaviour is by design.  As noted in the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Parameters):

> Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the
>   method is a function in [non-strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) code, `null` and `undefined` will
>   be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be
>   boxed.

Apparently, builtin functions are (treated as) strict mode code. Your own functions are not, unless, of course, you write a [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) function. :-)

This will be different in ECMAScript 5. From the [specification (PDF)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf):

> NOTE The thisArg value is passed without modification as the **this**
>   value. This is a change from Edition 3, where a **undefined** or **null**
>   thisArg is replaced with the global object and `ToObject` is applied to
>   all other values and that result is passed as the this value.

Here’s a [more direct link](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-15.3.4.4) to a non-normative but HTML version of the spec.

Comment: THX, so I can always call toString on all values safely anyway.

Comment: @yuyichao: Yes. But then, you might as well cast values to string using `String(...)`: `String(null)` and `String(this)` are shorter, will also work, and look less puzzling to beginners into the bargain.

Comment: errr.... what I mean by safely -> `toString.call(null)` will never tell me type of the current `this` object...

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

This is a standard behavior defined by ECMAScript 3rd Edition and yes, this is a method to check the type of any value, usually used to check arrays.

Comment: ~~~ wtf javascript ~~~ =D THX